# Validating fields in a Sencha Touch app

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am looking a solution similar to the `formBind`property in Ext.js but in ST2.4, validating my form, for example with a red underline in the specified field with an error.

How to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The property in ExtJS that determines if a *textfield* should be displayed with a red underline if invalid is **allowBlank**.

The equivalent property in SenchaTouch is **required**. The default behaviour is to place an asterisk next to the field label (no red line css is provided).

In SenchaTouch there is no form validation like in ExtJS. Therefore the **formBind** property you bind to buttons and the like in ExtJS to have them set to enabled/disabled does not exist.

The only thing I can think of is to extend the basic form panel and provide your own validation logic. I've implemented this in the following [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ojo). As long as you set any of your textfield items to have a **required** property that is *true* then the validation logic will kick in. Likewise the custom panel can be used without validation if none of the textfield items have the **required** property set.

You could also update the **validateFields** function I provided to update css classes if you want a visual indication that your form fields are invalid.

Hope this helps.

Comment: **Note:** the fiddle doesn't render on screen until you perform a mouse drag action in the body area (no idea why this happens for SenchaTouch).

Comment: I've updated the [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ojo) to include some basic CSS updates to the textfield items to demonstrate how you could update the appearance of an invalid field. The solution isn't bullet proof, but is intended to show how this may be achieved.